# Is there anyway to spin up an Amazon EC2 instance with javascript from the client?

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, client

question is same as the title.

Can javascript be used to spin up an ec2 instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [EC2 Javascript Scratchpad](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/1424) available. However it seems that it has not been updated for a while, but maybe you can start working with it.